MailMessage just spins and spins and never sends in .NET 8 with Office 365
I was following this link here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage?view=net-8.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN
I have done something similar in the past but I am now using Office 365 where everything is just hosted online.  Is there something else that needs to be setup for SMTP to work?  I just see the code spin and spin and it never progresses, never sends, just spins forever and tells me nothing.
using System.Collections;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Net;

string server = "smtp.office365.com";
var user = "user";
var password = "password";
var from = "a@b.com";
var to = "a@b.com";
var subject = "CSharp sent message";
var body = "Sent from code that is being made by Mail Message";

var message = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);

var client = new SmtpClient(server);
//client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
new NetworkCredential(user, password, "domain.com");
//client.Port = 465; //465 or 587

try
{
    //NOTE: Neither this or below line will work.  They both just spin.
    //await client.SendMailAsync(from, to, subject, body);
    client.Send(message);
    client.SendCompleted += (o, s) =>
    {
        o.ToString();
        var obj = s;
        obj.ToString();
    };
    Console.WriteLine("Sent");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _ = ex;
}

Picture for clarity.  I can step over line 24 and it doesn't fail, doesn't get to the next line.  Just doesn't do anything.


From the SmtpClient docs "We don't recommend that you use the SmtpClient class for new development because SmtpClient doesn't support many modern protocols. Use MailKit or other libraries instead."

If you still want to try use port 587 and set EnableSsl on SmtpClient as the server you try to use uses StartTls per documentation.

@Ralf Thanks.  Yeah I just need something quickly.  What you said works.  I just setup 587 as the port and client.EnableSsl = true.  I totally missed the note they had lol.  It was too obvious in all that blue box for me to see.

Port 465 is probably a better idea.

Does this answer your question? Unable to send hotmail from C#

@Charlieface in the common case yes but not when wanting to use SmtpClient. Implicit Tls is something SmtpClient simply can't do. One of the reasons SmtpClient is not recommended.

@Charlieface 465 will not work.  I tried that originally and it just spins and spins.  Even when 'client.EnableSsl = true' in my code.

@user246821 Similar but different.  .NET 8 didn't exist then.  They have a clear error.  Erasing this question would essentially get rid of cataloging what is happening.  Which I could not find.  No error and just spinning forever is not good.

So the answer is to change a few lines to:
var client = new SmtpClient(server, 587);
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password);

It appears 465 won't work and still just spins and spins -\ 0 /-.  I don't know, I don't work for MS.  Given it says not to keep using this method for new code I'm just using this temporarily for a small thing and then would recommend to anyone reading this to looking into mailkit
